# How to fix OSError: Initializing from file failed?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

So I am trying to import a file from Kaggle as a CSV, in order to create a data frame withpandas. I found the location of the file and then I entered the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Benito\Desktop\datasets\avocado-prices")
```

but then I get the error

```
    OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-9aba8b09b498> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Benito\Desktop\datasets\avocado-prices")
      2 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    683         )
    684 
--> 685         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    686 
    687     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    455 
    456     # Create the parser.
--> 457     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    458 
    459     if chunksize or iterator:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1133     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1134         if engine == "c":
-> 1135             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1136         else:
   1137             if engine == "python":

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1915         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1916 
-> 1917         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1918         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1919 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

OSError: Initializing from file failed
```

Comment: Backslash is a special character, you need to escape, i.e., use double backslash \\. Or you can prepend your string with `r` (for raw): `r'C:\...`

Comment: Like: ("C:\\\Users\Benito\\\Desktop\\\datasets\\\avocado-prices")?

Comment: Just double, not triple. I was trying to get around markdown on StackOverflow.

Comment: I have tried this before and I get the same error